# Android: ListView: Unable to setup single choice item in custom list item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, selectlistitem

I want to create a single item custom view and I have the following code, but it does not work. It checks multiple check boxes. Could someone please help me figure out the issue:

```
public class SingleChoiceRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable{

private CheckBox checkableView;

public SingleChoiceRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SingleChoiceRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SingleChoiceRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CheckBox getCheckableView() {
    return checkableView;
}

public void setCheckableView(CheckBox checkableView) {
    this.checkableView = checkableView;
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {

    if (this.checkableView != null){

        this.checkableView.setChecked(checked);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    if (this.checkableView != null){
        this.checkableView.isChecked());
        return this.checkableView.isChecked();
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {

    if (this.checkableView != null){

        this.checkableView.setChecked(!this.checkableView.isChecked());
    }


}

}


<com.xyz.view.SingleChoiceRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="47.5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dip"
        android:text="Group 1"
        android:textColor="#393c3d"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tickmark_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@drawable/tick_mark_icon_state_drawable"
        android:checked="false"
        android:padding="10dip" />

    <!-- <View -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="0.5dip" -->
    <!-- android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" -->
    <!-- android:background="@color/action_bar_divider_line" /> -->

</com.xyz.view.SingleChoiceRelativeLayout>
```

> ```
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/devices_list_view"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="17dip"
>     android:layout_marginRight="17dip"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="17dip"
>     android:divider="@color/action_bar_divider_line"
>     android:layout_below="@id/buttons_orbit"
>     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>     android:dividerHeight="1dip"
>     android:scrollbars="none"/>
> ```

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // Inflate the vertical list item
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_devices_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder();

            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tickmark_view);
            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnDeviceSelectionChangedListener());

            ((SingleChoiceRelativeLayout)convertView).setCheckableView(viewHolder.checkBox);

            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_name);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        setUpListItemView(viewHolder, position);
        return convertView;
    }




adapter = new DevicesListAdapter(DevicesActivity.this, devices);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.devices_list_view);
        list.setSelection(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        list.setAdapter(adapter);




private void setUpListItemView(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
        viewHolder.deviceName.setText(devicesList.get(position).getDeviceName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create on property for selecting index.

```
int selectedIndex = -1;
```

in `OnDeviceSelectionChangedListener()` get position of selected item and set that to `selectedIndex` then call notifyDatasetChanged() for refreshing list data

```
 ....
 selectedIndex = position;
 notifyDatasetChanged();
 .....
```

then in getView use this method

```
if (position == selectedIndex ) {
   viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
} else {
   viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

- Another answer

create one static property for selecting index in `SingleChoiceRelativeLayout`,

```
public static int selectedIndex = -1;
```

then in onItemClickListener:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                SingleChoiceRelativeLayout.selectedIndex = position;
                adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

            }
        });
```

then in getView check selected item.

```
  if (position == SingleChoiceRelativeLayout.selectedIndex ) {
       viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
       viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Comment: ok i shall try that. but why is my custom relative layout (SingleChoiceRelativeLayout) not getting the events? and thus not being able to handle this?

Comment: because you must store selected item, you can do that with one static property in `SingleChoiceRelativeLayout` class, can you post `setUpListItemView`

Comment: sorry could not understand your point but i have added the code as mentioned by you. could you please help?

Comment: what is your mean about "delays selection" ?